# Node.js app in subpath with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js, mod-proxy

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 x86 droplet on DigitalOcean with Apache 2.4.7 (the default from Ubuntu repositories). Also, I have a Node.js app running on port 3000, and want to map `/node*` path on root to `/*` the Node.js server (using Express).

**What I tried:**

- Enabled `mod_proxy` with `a2enmod proxy`.
- Modify `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and added a line with `ProxyPass /node http://localhost:3000/` to the end of `VirtualHost`.

**What I get:**

- `/node` proxied to `http://localhost:3000/`.
- `/node/help` proxied to `http://localhost:3000/` (which *is not right*).

Are there any other modifications I should do in order to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out I had `strict routing` set in Express, which doesn't tolerate `//help` for example.

**The solution:**
Omit trailing slash in `ProxyPass` directive, like so:

```
ProxyPass /node http://localhost:3000
```